# Open Directory with PyCharm

Tags: vim, pycharm

Here's something I find myself doing a lot:

1. Open PyCharm
2. File > Open Directory...

What I really want to be able to do is pass an argument to `C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm 2.6.1\bin\pycharm.exe` which has the current directory, so I can type is from cmd.exe (or the 'address bar' in Windows 7/8/Server 2012).

I note WebMatrix has as right-click context menu on Folders that says 'Open as a Web Site in Microsoft WebMatrix'. This is what I am trying to emulate.

As a secondary matter, I'd like to be able top open individual files just by typing 'pycharm main.py', as I do with gvim (e.g. `gvim main.py` or `gvim *.py`). I also note Vim on windows has a right-click 'Edit with Vim' context menu for files as well.

Answer (score 3):

PyCharm does support passing command line arguments to pycharm.exe. It will do "Open directory" if you pass in a directory name, and "Open file" if you pass in a file name. You might want to add the "bin" subdirectory of the PyCharm installation directory to PATH, so that you won't need to type the complete path to pycharm.exe.

At the moment PyCharm does not provide any shell extensions similar to what WebMatrix and gvim have, but it's possible that those will be added in a future version.

Comment: Ahh, very helpful, thank you! I see it appears to require the full path (e.g. pycharm c:\folder\ or pycharm c:\folder\example.py) so one can't just type pycharm example.py via cmd.exe or the address bar in explorer (like I can with notepad.exe or gvim). Is that correct? I think that's what threw me off initially.

Comment: @Aaron Yes, it **requires** FULL path to the folder/file, e.g. http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-94604